# How to model a parent user

Tags: mysql, sql, database-schema

We currently have an object (User) which is used to store a student, teacher or parent.

```
User { firstName not null, lastName not null, gender, firstName2, lastName2 }

Student John is represented as ("John", "Williams", "M", null, null)
Teacher Patrick is represented as ("Patrick", "Gold", "M", null, null)
Parent Josh / Cindy of student John is represented as ("Josh", "Mason", "M", "Cindy", "Crawford")
```

We are unable to model a use case where a student doesn't have a father. How should we model this?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me you're not telling us everything. As far as I can tell from your data, your database can't count teachers *or* students. And the data about parents doesn't seem to record who they're the parents *of*.

My advice: untangle information about identity from information about roles and relationships. Use separate tables for each--one for identitiy, one for roles (if you must), and one for relationships.

Also, consider whether a teacher can also a parent, and whether a student can become a parent. (Both those are possible in the real world.)

Comment: apologize, somehow missed the enumeration on the user entry which tells you whether the user is a Student, Parent, Teacher.

Comment: Teacher can be a Parent also (but will be always treated like a Teacher) whose children are studying in a institution. Students cannot be parents.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a table users with

- id (INT)
- user_name (CHAR)
- parent_id (INT - FK to id, NULL)
- role (ENUM('parent','student','teacher')) // is independent

Students, teachers and parents are all users. Parent_id refers creates a connection between a student and a parent. You can even create a foreign key to the same table from parent_id to id, but with NULL as default, so a student may exist without a father.

Comment: parent, student relationships is not the problem here. If a student doesn't have a father what will you fill in firstName, lastName (they are not nulls). But trying to store a mother's name in these fields might not make sense.

Comment: I am proposing you another structure that the one that you have, with no connection to it.

Comment: Not sure if I am getting you, but my problem still remains, how do you disntinguish a case where father is no more and its just the mother for the student. Can you give me some samples for my understanding